# Changing Value of a Register using C++

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to change an integer value of a register using C++.

This is what I've got...

```
DWORD_PTR* value_pointer= NULL;
__asm
{
    MOV [value_pointer], esp
}

// Create a pointer so we can modify the integer value stored in ESP, via value_pointer...
// We do +0x10 because the address is actually +0x10 ahead, I just couldn't compile the code using MOV [value_pointer], DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+0x10]
// Assume ESP+0x10 holds an integer value of 8
char* adjustable_value_pointer = ((char*)value_pointer + 0x10);

adjustable_value_pointer += 4;
```

Now if we assumed that ESP+0x10 originally held an integer value of 8, then when ESP+0x10 is referenced again (in assembly) after this code runs the value should now be 12, not 8.

But this doesn't seem to work for me...

Any help please?!

Comment: You seem to be modifying the pointer, not the referenced value. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: I want to modify the original value stored in ESP+0x10

Comment: In `((char*)value_pointer + 0x10;` you have mismatched parens, so the code shouldn't even compile.  Also, in `adjustable_value_pointer += 4;`, you are adjusting the value of the pointer, and not the thing being pointed at (as pointed out by @owacoder).

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: How are you so sure about where the compiler has placed things relative to `esp`?

Comment: Code that manages processor registers isn't C++. However, if modern C++ could have compiled on the PDP-11, then you could have used formally non-portable fixed address addressing to change the values of given registers. Because those registers were *memory mapped*. :)

Answer (score 0):

`value_pointer` should be a `DWORD_PTR` instead of a `DWORD_PTR*`, and you don't need to declare a new pointer, you can just use array indexing with `value_pointer` as the base (and adjust the index according to the stride):

```
value_pointer[4] += 4;
```

Will add the size of `4` `DWORD`s (0x16 bytes) to `value_pointer`, and access the memory at that address.